# CSS file and Image not working in ASP.NET project suddenly

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

[image]

I was coding an assignment for my school work and the css and image was working fine after some coding trying to add session into my code my css and image suddenly won't respond to the server.

It was working beforehand and now it doesn't work.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>eLEARNING - eLearning WEB</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <meta content="" name="description">
    
    <!-- Icon Font Stylesheet -->
    <!--        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!-- Libraries Stylesheet -->
    <link href="~/lib/animate/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Customized Bootstrap Stylesheet -->
    <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min_homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!-- Google Web Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

    <!-- Libraries Stylesheet -->
    <link href="~/lib/animate/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Customized Bootstrap Stylesheet -->
    <link href="~/css/bootstrap.min_homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

I check all my path and can see the CSS with the web dev tool
I tried turning on static content on is I reset my laptop

Comment: Is this locally or when deployed somewhere?  If it's local then the file must not exist at the path you think it does.  Within your project the files should be in `/wwwroot/css/` and `/wwwroot/lib/` folders

Comment: It is local and it was working before hand and suddenly after i coded some more it stoped and not only that i can access picture even though the dev tool can locate it though the path

Comment: In the console where it gives you the 404 errors, what does it show the full path to those files as and is that what you expect them to be?  Also have you tried closing visual studio and opening it again and re-building?

Comment: i have all my css in a folder but in the console it show bootstrap.min_homepage.css:1 with out the folder css . And i have try turning of visual studio and my laptop and turning on.

Comment: Everything in the wwwroot folder stopped working but the only picture i take from online is fine.

Comment: Please show your `Startup.cs` class. I think it might have to do with the placement of `app.UseStaticFiles();`

Comment: thank you very much i forgot to add useStatic file when i delete my old start up

Comment: Thank everyone for trying to help me.